# Delphi Resource Saving

Tags: delphi

I am having one Project with 4 Resources. My requirement is to save them in 4 different paths. So I defined the following codes:

```
procedure TMainForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  ResStream: TResourceStream;
begin
  ResStream := TResourceStream.CreateFromID(HInstance, 00001, RT_RCDATA);
  try
    ResStream.Position := 1;
    ResStream.SaveToFile('C:\MyFile.dll');
  finally
    ResStream.Free;
  end;
end;
```

I have got it from this forum. Then I have read http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/radstudio2007/RS2007_helpupdates/HUpdate4/EN/html/delphivclwin32/!!MEMBEROVERVIEW_Classes_TResourceStream.html. But **TResourceStream.Position** is not clear to me. Whether for the first Resource it should be 1, for the second it sould be 2 and so on.

Comment: A `TResourceStream` loads only 1 resource (the one you give with the second parameter to the constructor you used above (you used `00001`, which could be `1` instead). You'll need to free the stream and create it again with the second identifier, free it again and create with the 3rd, and so forth. You've asked way too many questions in a single post here. The general rule is "One question per post". You've asked at least 3 separate ones (`TResourceStream`, `SaveToFile` and confirmation, and `GetHashCode` are three separate topics).

Comment: @Rubi I converted into a single question

Comment: From the original question: *If the file already exist then SaveToFile('C:\MyFile.dll') will just overwrite the existing and will ask for confirmation always? If so, how to off the confirmation dialog?* No, it will overwrite without asking for confirmation.

Comment: This one: *Another requirement is that after saving the first file the memory should be reallocated using FreeInstance and NewInstance, but how?* That makes no sense at all. You should not be thinking about calling those functions. You destroy the stream and the memory is returned to the memory manager.

Comment: And this one: *And the last question is that by calling GetHashCode Method, is it possible to check the HASH value of any file? If so, how it can be possible? No example is available regarding this.* Sure you can get a hash for a stream. How do you want to do it? Any particular hash? Calling `GetHashCode` on a stream won't do anything useful. You probably want something like SHA1.

Comment: @David: Why did you bother to convert into a single question if you're going to answer all four of them here? They should be posted as actual questions (by Rubi), so that they (and the answers) are available to future users searching for them. Comments aren't appropriate for this use, and you know that already. You also just threw away the opportunity to provide some education on how to properly use SO.

Comment: Geez, if we all always followed strictly by every little rule, life would be so boring...

Comment: Thanks David. Your have guessed the right. I want something like SHA1 using *GetHashCode Method*.

Comment: @Ken I don't think Qs 2 and 3 will be useful for future visitors. I don't think Q1 will be. It's too localized. Q4 could be useful but I only hinted at that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this line

```
ResStream.Position := 1;
```

you are setting the position of the stream. That's akin to setting the file pointer in file. The value of [`Position`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TStream.Position) bears no relation to the resource number. The documentation describes it like this:

> Indicates the current offset into the stream for reading and writing.
>
> Use Position to obtain the current position of the stream. This is the
>   number of bytes from the beginning of the streamed data.

In fact you should not set `Position` at all. It serves no purpose. You code can be:

```
procedure SaveResourceToFile(const ID: Integer; const FileName: string);
var
  Stream: TResourceStream;
begin
  Stream := TResourceStream.CreateFromID(HInstance, ID, RT_RCDATA);
  try
    Stream.SaveToFile(FileName);
  finally
    Stream.Free;
  end;
end;
```

So you need to call this function four times, each time passing the ID of the resource and the destination filename.

Comment: +1. Beat me to it. :-) You might want to clarify that having 4 resources in one file still means you have 4 separate resources, though; that seems to be the main misunderstanding by the poster.

Answer (score 1):

The `Position` property of a `TResourceStream` means the same as it does in any other `TStream` descendant. It defines the current read or write position within the stream's data. Setting `Position := 1` means that the next read or write operation will start at the second byte of the data.

You generally wouldn't want to set `Position` to anything other than zero since you would want to process the entire stream. However, in this case, **it doesn't matter**. `SaveToFile` always writes the *entire* contents of the stream to the file. The current position is irrelevant.

Load each resource separately (i.e., four separate calls to `TResourceStream.Create`) and save each one.

Comment: Thanks. Thanks a lot.. I think, from memory I can call a Special Type of Font used in TMainForm without saving it into the PC.

Comment: OK. But what's that got to do with anything in the question? If you want to know about fonts, then post a question asking about fonts.